# C# CS0266 using "this" to current instance of class

Tags: c#, debugging, inheritance

I have am creating a program where a person can equip a sandwich. I keep getting error CS0266 and I can't figure out why? I am using this to refer to the current instance of the person.

```
 class Sandwich : IEquip
 {
    public void Equip(Person person)
    {
        person.EquippedSandwich = this; //I get the error on "this" here.
    }
    ...
  }     

  interface IEquip
  { 
     void Equip(Person person);
  }
```

---

```
class Person
{
  private Sandwich equippedSandwich;
  //methods and properties

  public BiteSandwich equippedSandwich
  {
      get {  return EquippedSandwich; }
      set { equippedSandwich = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `EquippedSandwich`? Can you show the defintion of `Person` class?

Comment: Can you show the `Person` class?

Comment: "I am using this to refer to the current instance of the person."??? Sentence  sounds very strange - `this` in the sample is of type `Sandwich` which is unlikely person...

Comment: private Sandwich equippedSandwich

Answer (score 3):

Usually you get this error when your code tries to convert between two types that cannot be ***implicitly*** converted, but where an ***explicit*** conversion is available.

You need to do an explicit cast with a type that `EquippedSandwich` belongs to.

```
 person.EquippedSandwich = (IEquip)this;
```